# histogram code in c++ shows some crazy unexpected numbers

Tags: c++, histogram

i wrote a little program to determine the histogram of a picture as a part of my task:

```
void histogram(const SimpleGrayImage &img, long (&tab)[256]) {  //SimpleGrayImage is a given class from our prof
int val = 0;
int count = 1;

while (val < 256) {
    for (int i = 0; i < img.height(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < img.width(); j++) {
            if (val == img[i][j]) {    //with img[][] you can get the integer value (between 0<256)
                tab[val] = count;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    count = 0;
    val++;
}
```

}

in the next step im going to print the array:

```
int main(){

SimpleGrayImage img(RESOURCES_PATH "/black.pgm"); //loads a black image with the resolution of 512x512
long arr[256];

histogram(img, arr);

for(int j=0;j<256;j++){
    cout<<"grey tone: "<<j<<" count: "<<arr[j]<<"\n"<<endl;
}
```

}

when i run this program the console gives the right information:

```
grey tone: 0 count: 262144
```

.
.
.

the other grey tones (from 1-235) also gives the right information (0) but then the console show some crazy numbers and i can't explain why this is happening:

```
grey tone: 236 count: 288392707021528753
grey tone: 237 count: 140734701956328
grey tone: 238 count: 21
grey tone: 239 count: 1
grey tone: 240 count: 4392816744
grey tone: 241 count: 140734851732223
grey tone: 242 count: 140734701956144
grey tone: 243 count: 140734851576438
grey tone: 244 count: 140734701956176
```

.
.
.

so can you guys give me a solution for my problem.
thank you :)

Comment: The posted answer is correct. Also you should check your method. The outer while loop is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some value does not exist at all, then the fact that you don't initialize the array to zeros hits you.

Try something like:

```
long arr[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    arr[i] = 0;
}
histogram(img, arr);
```

Or alternatively, handle the initialization within your `histogram` function.

Comment: Thanks Pukku!! now it works fine :) thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize your array. So you're printing some chunks of memory where you can't know wether there is a value or not.

Run this code to initialize `arr` before calling `histogram`.

```
for  (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    arr[i] = 0;
```